# Why was this edit approved?

Tags: discussion, edits, review, suggested-edits

I came across [this suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1755990) while reviewing posts. When I went to reject the edit, I was surprised to see that it had already been approved. How do these types of edits through the approval process?

If people are simply blindly approving posts, what can be done about this? Should there be some sort of post-review process where we can flag the review, the approves of which get a slap on the wrist? Or maybe one less review per day?

Comment: Comments Purged Daily / Arguments forestalled nightly / turtles, man, turtles

Answer (score 9):

When reviewing edits through the review queue, people quickly glance at an edit and have their mouse pointer already over the appropriate button (*Approve*, *Reject*). At my first glance (less than a second of looking at it) this was a user attempting to improve the formatting on a post. Only because you were seeing an issue with this edit did I look at it closer, and saw the obscenity.

The review queues make people more likely to decide on first impressions, and then edits such as these can slip through. Also, maybe some other people rejected the edit but the approvals dwarfed the rejections.

In this case it seems that two edits were done at the same time. The first changed the formatting *and* removed the obscenity that was present in the original post, and the second only changed the formatting. Because the second edit overrode the first, it looks as if it introduced the profanity, but it didn't.

But I agree, it should never have been approved because it clearly marks the obscene words (you can't tell whether the editor introduced them from that edit alone), and possibly because it is too minor. This would make a good edit review test.